# Xamarin iOS ViewCellRenderer

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I tried to customize `UITableViewCell`. I did it like explained here: [Xamarin Customizing a ViewCell](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell/)

So far so good.
Now I tried to implement the ui of the cell in a xib. That does now almost work. I just have two problems:

1. The row height of the cells stays at 44.
2. How can I access the ui elements like labels to change their text?

Here is my code:

ViewCellRenderer:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
{
  var NativeViewCell = (NativeViewCell)item;

  cell = reusableCell as NativeiOSCell;
  if (cell == null)
    cell = new NativeiOSCell(item.GetType().FullName, NativeViewCell);
  else
    cell.NativeViewCell.PropertyChanged -= OnNativeViewCellPropertyChanged;

  NativeViewCell.PropertyChanged += OnNativeViewCellPropertyChanged;
  cell.UpdateCell(NativeViewCell);
  tv.RowHeight = 102;
  return cell;
}
```

NativeiOSCell:

```
public NativeiOSCell(string cellId, NativeViewCell cell) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
{
  NativeViewCell = cell;
  UITableViewCell view = (UITableViewCell) UINib.FromName("Layout1", NSBundle.MainBundle).Instantiate(null, null)[0];
  this.Bounds = view.Bounds;
  ContentView.AddSubviews(view.ContentView.Subviews);
}
```

Comment: Ok, my second Question is done. They were of course in the subviews so that I can access them from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since  M.D. just created a `ViewCellRenderer` not `ListViewRenderer` , we can't access `GetHeightForRow` or `EstimatedHeight` method.

#### Solution 1：Set RowHeight on ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" RowHeight="100">
```

#### Solution 2：Set HasUnevenRows True and set Height on ViewCell

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:NativeCell  Height="100" Name="{Binding Name}" Category="{Binding Category}" ImageFilename="{Binding ImageFilename}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the table source of your table, because the problem is not related with your custom cell, the problem is the method in the table source that assign this value for default

```
public override nfloat EstimatedHeight(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return base.EstimatedHeight(tableView, indexPath);
    }
```

try to put something like

```
public override nfloat EstimatedHeight(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 104;
    }
```

and check this value for the Table View don't be automatic and put the value of the your custom cell

[image]
I hope this help let me know.